# Android Studio preview not link a barrier grafically

Tags: android, barrier

Sure it´s a stupid thing, but I can´t find it....

It´s a typically use example for barries: https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html

When I try to connect a view with the barrier, it not appears a point link....and I can´t.
[1]: https://i.ibb.co/25NYBwC/barrier-1.jpg

I updated Android Studio to version 4.1 and I use androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2

This is the code without the button linked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="203dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="130dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView,textView2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```